# Remove black and white effect from halftone filter

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

In Brad Larson's excellent `GPUImage`, there is a halftone filter which also turns the picture black and white. I am just wanting the halftone effect without the black and white and I was wondering can anyone tell me how what I can remove from the following code to fix this? Have been playing around with it, but virtually have no experience in `openGL` and am not sure what to eliminate.

```
NSString *const kGPUImageHalftoneFragmentShaderString = SHADER_STRING
(
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;

 uniform highp float fractionalWidthOfPixel;
 uniform highp float aspectRatio;
 uniform highp float dotScaling;

 const highp vec3 W = vec3(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);

 void main()
 {
     highp vec2 sampleDivisor = vec2(fractionalWidthOfPixel, fractionalWidthOfPixel / aspectRatio);

     highp vec2 samplePos = textureCoordinate - mod(textureCoordinate, sampleDivisor) + 0.5 * sampleDivisor;
     highp vec2 textureCoordinateToUse = vec2(textureCoordinate.x, (textureCoordinate.y * aspectRatio + 0.5 - 0.5 * aspectRatio));
     highp vec2 adjustedSamplePos = vec2(samplePos.x, (samplePos.y * aspectRatio + 0.5 - 0.5 * aspectRatio));
     highp float distanceFromSamplePoint = distance(adjustedSamplePos, textureCoordinateToUse);

     lowp vec3 sampledColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, samplePos ).rgb;
     highp float dotScaling = 1.0 - dot(sampledColor, W);

     lowp float checkForPresenceWithinDot = 1.0 - step(distanceFromSamplePoint, (fractionalWidthOfPixel * 0.5) * dotScaling);

     gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(checkForPresenceWithinDot), 1.0);
 }
);
```

Comment: To get color back you could try changing the last line to gl_FragColor = vec4(checkForPresenceWithinDot * sampledColor, 1.0);. I'm not sure if this is what you are going for since I don't quite understand halftone filters but it will be colored instead of black and white.

Comment: @user3256930 - That works, thanks. Do you want to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the last line to

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(checkForPresenceWithinDot * sampledColor, 1.0);
```

This will make the effect have color instead of black and white only.